# Unknown method SfGuardUserTable::retrieveByUsername Symfony1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm wondering why I got this error when installing `sfDoctrineGuard` plugin in `symfony 1.4` project

stack trace:

```
SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Table.php line 2856 ...
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->getRecordInstance(), $method . 'TableProxy'), $arguments);

        } catch (Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException $e) {}
        throw new Doctrine_Table_Exception(sprintf('Unknown method %s::%s', get_class($this), $method));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs when you run doctrine build all or build model command from the command line.

If the `sf_guard_user` table exists in your database, running either of these commands generates an empty `SfGuardUserTable` class in your `\lib\model` folder and this gets used instead of the  `sfGuardUserTable` class sitting in your plugin folder, which does contain a `retrieveByUsername` method.

Removing the `SfGuard____`  classes from inside your lib folder would fix the problem.

I used the build commands quite often and got a bit fed up with doing this each time. I eventually moved the code from within the plugin folder into the lib directory which isn't really recommended. But I don't think the sfGuardUser plugin is maintained any more, so if you know what you're doing you could give it a try.

Comment: When you run `doctrine:build` it should generate the classes in your `lib/model/doctrine/sfGuardPlugin` and those classes should extend the `PluginGuard__` classes. If the task does not do that for you extend those classes manually, so you won't have to remove them after every `doctrine:build`.